# Was Lord Shiva first messenger of Islam?

Tags: shiva, history, other-religions, islam

Some Muslim leaders say [Lord Shiva was the  first messenger of Islam](http://m.timesofindia.com/india/Lord-Shiva-first-messenger-of-Islam-Muslim-cleric-says/articleshow/46306675.cms)

Is it true or just a rumor being spread  amongst the people?

Comment: For the Lord Shiva - or SadaShiv This is like the Third and most essential power IN GOD Sentence
Destroyer When the world starts at that time Tamasa Guna was shiva and Aadi Shakti creates this whole world. So their part in this universe as Destroyer, and Generally if Muslims worship for Shiva is a Really Good thing for them. And if they are saying Shiva is first messenger. So this thing goes like if the world starts with them so they are the first messenger to whole of world not for some community.

Comment: False. Utter false. Don't believe this. Shiva is PARAMESWARA which means Supreme Lord. So, as prophet whom should he praise. However, Rudra, his destructive aspect, incarnated as sages to teach Yoga techniques in every transition times of Dwapara and Kali Yuga. He only teaches Yoga techniques to realize self and to free people from cycle of birth and death.

Comment: Hmmm...turning over the coin, maybe Islam was a messenger of Lord Shiva? All religions lead to the One.

Comment: There is no factual basis in this, these are failed attempts at digestion of Hinduism by Islam.

Comment: According to my finding Shiva was not only messenger of Islam. He was the first messenger for entire World. In Yoga Lord Shiva is considered as Adi Yogi (Not God). He was a great teacher. It is Shiva who taught us Yoga, Dance, Martial arts etc. So I believe he is a great teacher to all man kind.

Comment: Who was the messenger is mentioned quite clearly in the Bhavisya Purana.An incarnation of a demon actually.But he did win a boon from Lord Shiva(in previous birth)

Comment: Siva is not the messenger of Islam except in the sense that, as God, He is the author of all religions, even those that deny His existence.

Comment: @Rickross  It is well known bhavisya purana is not authentic.

Comment: But not known to me :) ... all I know is It is one of the 18 Puranas and we can use it as ref. on this site  .. whether it was interpolated later is a subject of debate .. @ShashwatAsthana

Comment: @Rickross Asking as you are an old member, have you read all major Purana?

Comment: No I have not read all of them ..that's a huge syllabus .. @ShashwatAsthana

Answer (score 1):

First messenger of Islam is Adam, the first human being. God created Adam first and then from him Eve and from this pair we all emerged so we are all like members of a big family. Thus, Islam preaches universal brotherhood.

“O Mankind! We have created you from a single pair of male and female, and made you in to nations and tribes, that you may know one another (not that you may hate each other). Surely the most honourable of you in the sight of Allah is (he, who is) the most righteous of you….” [Quran 49:13]

One mufti mohammad of luknow I guess commented that Adam-Eve are actually Shiva-parvati.  Not sure if he wanted to gain political benefit from that comment or wanted to bring peace between Hindu-Muslims but this comment is not correct.

As far as I know Shiva first appeared in Vedas as Rudra, one of the 33 devatas. Later he appears extensively in Hindu mythological books like in Shiva puranam etc.,

Thus equating Adam and Shiva is nothing but intellectual fraud. We should present scriptures as they are without such manipulations.